# Another Window over QMainWindow in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, qmainwindow

Can i have another window over main window in Qt , and how can i implement it? I have a plugin which must return another window. I created in plugin a `QWidget` and set it as `centralWidget` but my app crashes.Anyway this will not show two windows at same time . Could someone explain how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any new widget created without a parent will show up as a new window. Don't try to reset 'centralWidget' unless you don't actually want the old one anymore.

If all you want is a main window whose contents change, take a look at [StackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html).